# Click to flip div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like a div to flip and show its 'back' if a user hovers over it. The back would be equal size to the front of the div but contain different text.

This is what I have tried

```js
$('.hover').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('flip');
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('flip');
});
$('.click').toggle(function() {
  $(this).addClass('flipswing');
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('flipswing');
});
```

```css
.panel {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.panel .front {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #6b7077;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.panel .back {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #6b7077;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-179deg);
  transform: rotateY(-179deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.panel.flip .front {
  transform: rotateY(179deg)
}

.panel.flip .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0);
}

.panel {
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.swing .front,
.swing .back {
  width: 140px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 170px 0;
  transform-origin: 170px 0;
}

.swing .front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateY(0);
}

.swing .back {
  background-color: #555;
  /* hiding this side, so get darker */
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg) translateX(198px) translateZ(2px);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg) translateX(198px) translateZ(2px);
}

.swing.flipswing .front {
  background-color: #222;
  /* hiding this side, so get darker */
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.swing.flipswing .back {
  background-color: #80888f;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0) translateX(198px) translateZ(2px);
  transform: rotateY(0) translateX(198px) translateZ(2px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
  <div class="hover panel">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="single_instructor">
        <div class="author">
          <img src="{% static 'second/images/people/person.jpg' %}" style="max-width:100%;max-height:100%;" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="author_decs">
          <h4>User Name</h4><br>
          <p class="profession">Job Title</p>
          <p>Country</p>
          <div class="social_icons">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      This the back
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As it currently stands when I hover over a div, the div does not rotate and show me the back card

Comment: it is working fine

Comment: @ashishsingh Your edit changed this into a snippet. JavaScript in snippets is loaded after the DOM contents. The issue might be that OP runs the JavaScript before the DOM is fully loaded. In which case OP might need to add the JavaScript in an "onload" script. `$(function () { /* your JavaScript here */ })`. But this isn't made clear from the question context.

Comment: oh i am so sorry

Comment: i am sorry, i  have rolled back.. thanks for pointing out @3limin4t0r

Comment: OP Could you elaborate when you run the provided JavaScript? Is the `<script>` tag located in the `<head>`? Do you already have an "onload" callback? Or do you have the `<script>` tag at the bottom of the `<body>`?

Comment: @3limin4t0r I have the tag at the bottom of the body closing tag. I do not have an onload callback

Comment: Ah, I didn't read the comments and made it a snippet again :P

Comment: @Emm Could you add `console.log(".hover element count:", $('.hover').length)` to the top of your script and check if the elements are loaded at all when the script runs? What is the result of this? Do you get an `0` for the `.hover` element count?

Comment: Also the question title and content are in conflict. *"Click to flip"* in the title followed  by  *"if a user hovers over it"* in the content. Which of the two are you trying to achieve? Could you resolve this conflict?